# Is elasticsearch java client backward compatible with server?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Can someone let me know if elasticsearch java client 2.4..x backward compatible with elasticsearch server 2.3.1?

I couldn't locate this information anywhere in elasticsearch docs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be addressedt to the vendor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in this link:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html

> The client must have the same major version (e.g. 2.x, or 5.x) as the
>   nodes in the cluster. Clients may connect to clusters which have a
>   different minor version (e.g. 2.3.x) but it is possible that new
>   functionality may not be supported. Ideally, the client should have
>   the same version as the cluster.

they are compatible. However, the ideal scenario is that both client and nodes are in the same version.

Comment: [This page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-compatibility.html) also mentions that client and server versions should be aligned, and using a more recent version of the client could cause trouble.